# CKEditor creates unwanted whitespaces after tags

Tags: ckeditor

I am using dokuwiki and try to setup CKeditor, using the config parameters. The problem that I face: When a user enters e.g.

[image: example]

after saving it becomes:

[image: example after]

the whitespace between ^ and x is created by a space after the HTML tag (which in the example is <strong>).

```
<p>
Die Eingabe 3<strong>^</strong> x führt zu 3<sup>x</sup>.
</p>
```

I have checked [HTML Output formatting](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_output_format) of ckeditor and tried to implement it, but it makes no difference, there is still a line break for the html tags. This is the code I am using in the config:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev)
{
    // var myTags = new Array ('p','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6');
    var myTags = new Array ('span', 'strong', 'sup', 'sub');

    for(var Tag in myTags) 
    {
        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules(myTags[Tag], 
        {
            // indicates that this tag causes indentation on line breaks inside of it.
            // indent : false,
            // inserts a line break before the opening tag.
            breakBeforeOpen : false,
            // inserts a line break after the opening tag.
            breakAfterOpen : false,
            // inserts a line break before the closing tag.
            breakBeforeClose : false,
            // inserts a line break after the closing tag.
            breakAfterClose : false
        });
   }
});
```

My guess was that `breakAfterClose : false` would solve the problem, but it does not.

PS: I am also not sure if the DokuWiki software and the used ckgedit plugin are interfering here...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is an issue with DokuWiki's ckgedit plugin, see solution and bug fix here: https://github.com/turnermm/ckgedit/issues/186